# ReactJS when add proxy to package.json css modules stop working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

I add in my package.json proxy for making request to server runing on other port.

after that, my module css styles stop working, in the devTools i found that the styles are loading well, but classnames for DOM elements are not loading at all.

How it looks now:

[image]

How it should be:

[image]

some page code:

```
import styles from "./LoginPage.module.css";
export default function LoginPage() {
 return (
          <div className={styles.LoginPage}>
         </div>
     );
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "job-bot-admin-panel",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.4",
        "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.21",
        "react": "^18.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "^0.9.5",
        "react-select": "^5.2.2",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your filename is incorrect. for css modules you don't need to add `.module` to the filename, just name it `LoginPage.css` and import it with that same name and your styles should be fine. React is getting confused with your `module` filename.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try it, but why before I set proxy all my module.css styles work fine, I remember on my other projects css not working like modules if I don't name it with .module.css?

Comment: Did it work for you?